# How to resolve 'partition not assigned' warning in BigQuery sink connector for Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

How to resolve 'partition not assigned' warning in BigQuery sink connector (v2.5) for Kafka Connect?

I set the default partitions for a kafka topic to 8 and therefore the maximum tasks for the BigQuery sink connector (v2.5) to 8.

I get the following warning in the logs (just an excerpt):

> Ignoring invalid task provided offset public.production_runs-0/OffsetAndMetadata{offset=24870, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''} -- partition not assigned

I am not sure how to resolve it. Still it seems as if it is working since records are written to BigQuery.

Does the number of tables have anything to do with it?